# Add leading zero to a column if length of cell is 2 in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Code 
111
222
333
34
43
A5
```

I want to add leading zeros to values that have a length of 2 so the desired dataframe is this:

```
Code
111
222
333
034
043
0A5
```

I tried this:

```
df['Code']=df['Code'].apply(str)
df['length']=df['Code'].str.len()

def addzero(row):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['length'] == 2:
            row['Code'] = "0"+ row['Code']

df.apply(lambda x: addzero(x), axis=1)
```

However this does not work, please suggest a better way to accomplish this :) thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this. zfill in pandas.
[enter link description here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html)

If this answers your question then do mark my answer as accepted

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `rjust`

```
df.Code = df.Code.str.rjust(3, '0')
0    111
1    222
2    333
3    034
4    043
5    0A5
Name: Code, dtype: object
```

Comment: it's nice one :) +1

Comment: i started playing with `ljust` and `rjust` to dynamically make some nicely formatted SQL CTAS statements and it's awesome. +1

Comment: THANK YOU! this is awesome haha